# SQL return first result for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Query

```
Select ID, Date, Type, TypeID, Active from TableName
```

Results

```
ID      | Date                    | Type   | TypeID | Active 
------  | ----------------------- | ------ | ------ | ------
16026690| 2017-08-02 20:35:51.000 | Banana | 121    | 0
------  | ----------------------- | ------ | ------ | ------
16026695| 2017-08-02 20:43:03.000 | Banana | 121    | 0
------  | ----------------------- | ------ | ------ | ------
16026700| 2017-08-02 20:35:51.000 | Orange | 125    | 0
------  | ----------------------- | ------ | ------ | ------
16026705| 2017-08-02 20:43:03.000 | Orange | 125    | 0
------  | ----------------------- | ------ | ------ | ------
16026706| 2017-08-02 20:47:51.000 | Orange | 128    | 0
------  | ----------------------- | ------ | ------ | ------
16026706| 2017-08-02 20:50:51.000 | Orange | 128    | 0
------  | ----------------------- | ------ | ------ | ------
16026777| 2017-08-02 20:58:03.000 | Orange | 128    | 0
```

I want to return the most recent record for each Type/TypeID

So the results I want to see for the above table is:

```
ID      | Date                    | Type   | TypeID | Active 
------  | ----------------------- | ------ | ------ | ------
16026695| 2017-08-02 20:43:03.000 | Banana | 121    | 0
------  | ----------------------- | ------ | ------ | ------
16026705| 2017-08-02 20:43:03.000 | Orange | 125    | 0
------  | ----------------------- | ------ | ------ | ------
16026777| 2017-08-02 20:58:03.000 | Orange | 128    | 0
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to achieve this?
I am using MS SQL 2016

Comment: What database you using?

Comment: Depends on what database type you are using. For MySQL you would `order by Date` then `limit 1`.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in PawelCz comment the link shows you that it can be done using the following:

```
;WITH temp AS (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY [TypeID] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS rownum 
    FROM TableName 
)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    temp
WHERE 
    rownum = 1
```

Comment: Based on the edit made by OP you need to change from [Type] to [TypeID]

Answer (score 2):

You can query as below:

```
Select top (1) with ties * from yourtable
   Order by Row_Number() over(Partition by [TypeId] order by [Date] desc)
```

Comment: I've never seen this usage before. How does it compare to domgreen's answer (that's the way I do this) in terms of efficiency?

Comment: This is other way just to avoid subquery but still avoiding subquery will result in extra sort operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ID, Date, Type, TypeID, Active from TableName ORDER BY Date Limit 1
```

If you're using MySql this should work fine , if you use SQL Server , I suggest `TOP 1` or 'ROW_NUMBERS' instead of `LIMIT 1`

Comment: I am using SQL Server, I cannot use top 1, as there are many other results that come back, and I want to select the most recent for each type ID by Date, does this make more sense?